# How to get Azure Resource Health from API using ResourcesManagementClient?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I'm specifically trying to fetch the information described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/availabilitystatuses/listbysubscriptionid

Is `ResourcesManagementClient` the way to go?

If so, how can I use it to fetch the availability statuses from the *Microsoft.ResourceHealth* provider?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

1. Create a service principal and assign Azure RBAC role to the sp
2. Install sdk

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" Version="3.13.0-preview" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.30.1" />
```

3. Code

```
            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenantDomain))
                .Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                     .ExecuteAsync();

            var cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);

            ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(cred);
            resourceManagementClient.SubscriptionId = subscription;
            ///For example
            ///var resource = await resourceManagementClient.Resources.GetAsync(
            ///           "testdata",
            ///           "Microsoft.Compute",
            ///           "virtualMachines/testdocker" + "/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth",
            ///           "availabilityStatuses",
            ///           "current",
            ///           "2020-05-01"
            ///    );
            ///
            ///
            ///
            var resource = await resourceManagementClient.Resources.GetAsync(
                   "<the resource group of the resource your want to>",
                   "<the namesapce of the resource your want to>",
                   "<the resource path of the resource your want to>" + "/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth",
                   "availabilityStatuses",
                   "current",
                   "2020-05-01"

                );

            Console.WriteLine(resource.Properties);
```

[image]